# Change modifier key from Alt to Super/windows key

Tags: linux

I'm running Blender on a fairly customized linux distribution and Alt is already taken by another program. I therefore wonder if there's an easy way to change to modifier key Alt to Super key globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is! This is for Blender v2.8-rc1.

Open *Edit -> Preferences...* from the menu bar, select *Keymap* from the left sidebar, and then *Export...* in the top right to export your current keymap. In the dialogue that opens, check the *Export Key Configuration -> All Keymaps* box.

Save the keymap somewhere. In the keymap file, replace every instance of `"alt"` (including the quotes) with `"oskey"`. Go back to the *Keymap* pane in the Blender preferences and import your changed keymap. Whenever this keymap is selected, all the shortcuts in your previous keymap that used <kbd>Alt</kbd> will now use <kbd>Super</kbd>.

Of course, if you're already using <kbd>OSkey</kbd> for some shortcuts, this solution may cause collisions. The default keymap for Blender under Linux doesn't use it at all, though, and I assume based on your question that you haven't modified it to.

As a side note, there isn't actually a way to tell Blender to use <kbd>Super</kbd> in place of <kbd>Alt</kbd>  globally below the keymap level, as far as I can tell, short of patching it to do so. Blender only understands four modifier keys, <kbd>Shift</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> , and <kbd>OSkey</kbd>. <kbd>OSkey</kbd> represents a different key depending on the OS: <kbd>Super</kbd> under Linux, <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> under Windows, and <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> under macOS.

Shortcuts consist of a single key other than those four plus some combination of them. All keycodes are hardcoded with no way to change them in Blender's configuration; the raw keycodes seem to be in `source/blender/windowmanager/wm_event_types.h` but I'm not sure how they correspond to keycodes outside of Blender.

However, you might be able to patch `source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_wm.c`, changing the item(s) for the key(s) you want to use in place of <kbd>Alt</kbd> in `rna_enum_event_type_items[]` (`OSKEY`, in this case) to use the values in the items for `LEFTALTKEY` or `RIGHTALTKEY`. I haven't actually tried this, so I'm not positive it would work; it would be a hacky solution if it did, but I'm not sure there's a better way without making big changes to Blender.